# Committing a transaction while inside a datareader loop

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm looping inside a reader and updating a different table the reader is reading from. Every 1000 loops I want to commit() the transation but it's giving the error:

> The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are
>   pending requests working on this transaction.

I've seen 2 other answers and one of them said close the reader but we obviously can't do that as we're using that data from the reader to run an update statement and update another table.

So the question is, if you create a transaction on a connection, then you have a datareader looping over some sql command, how can I, within the datareader loop, run an update command and commit() the transaction inside the datareader loop?

Comment: Can you post your code?  You could be running into concurrency issues which may require a different transaction isolation level setting in your transaction.

Comment: It's pretty messy and in-depth code as it's injecting this into the existing datareader loop that was already in the app. It's tough to break it out. I was just curious if doing something like this is common or if it's not something possible.

Comment: you could use a second, independent connection for the transacted write operations (why would you use a transaction at all, if you commit it every 1000 rows? is it not just a bulk update?) or play with the datareader constructor options, there is the so called firehose mode, and there used to be an "updatable" mode I don't remember exactly, which behave differently inside transactions, may be worth looking up.

Comment: [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx) also looks like a solution: "If two batches are submitted under a MARS connection, one of them containing a SELECT statement, the other containing a DML statement, the DML can begin execution within execution of the SELECT statement"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to achieve this:

1) Open a second connection and use it for the transactional updates.

2) Use the "multiple active resultsets" option of SQL Server:

> If two batches are submitted under a MARS connection, one of them containing a SELECT statement, the other containing a DML statement, the DML can begin execution within execution of the SELECT statement.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The update is happening on a temp table (# in sql server) so guessing a 2nd connection wouldn't see that? Maybe a global (##) temp table then instead to see it?

Comment: True, one session cannot see another session's temporary tables. why do you need that transaction again, then? if the updated table is private to your connection, and you are not multithreading on it, I do not see how the transaction would add any value.

Comment: Speed. Without it, we'd be making an implicit transaction on each update statement we run, which there are hundreds of thousands being done as the reader is looping over every record. The existing process is not efficient but that's not our task right now to tackle. It's to piggy back off of it.

Comment: how many rows does the data reader return? if its just a few thousands, and just a key each, load it to memory (e.g. `IList<int>`), close the reader, and then loop for the update.

Comment: just saw your comment about "injecting ... into the datareader loop"... out of ideas, then. maybe simple recovery model in connection with `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted` on the connection?